# SQl Query: The last one by date from each company?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that includes  3 columns `Company`, `DateTime` and `Price`.

I want to get the last row ordered by date of each company like

```
Google, 2012/7/17 5:24:32, 23
Google, 2012/7/17 5:46:23, 72
Google, 2012/7/17 5:43:46, 15
Apple, 2012/7/17 5:24:45, 36
Apple, 2012/7/17 5:26:42, 57
Apple, 2012/7/17 5:15:12, 25
```

and the desired results would be:

```
Google, 2012/7/17 5:46:23, 72
Apple, 2012/7/17 5:26:42, 57
```

Comment: What [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system)?

Comment: all of these show me the all rows

Comment: Do you have to deal with duplicate time values?  If so, what do you want?  All of them or just one?

Answer (score 1):

If your DBMS is `SQL-Server` (at least 2005) you can use a `CTE` with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Company, DateTime, Price
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM Table
)
SELECT Company, DateTime, Price
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a DBMS-agnostic solution and should work regardless of what DBMS you're using (as you did not specify):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT company, MAX(datetime) AS maxdate
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY company
) b ON a.company = b.company AND a.datetime = b.maxdate
ORDER BY a.datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    Company, DateTime,Price 
from
    (
    select *,row_number() over (Partition by Company order by Date desc) as sno 
      from table
    ) as t
where sno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select t.* from <table> t join
(select Company,max(DateTime) max_DateTime
from <table>
group by Company)a
on t.Company=a.Company
and t.DateTime=a.max_DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy one:

```
select company, MAX(datetime), price 
from table_name
group by company;
```